# Command Button not working in child nodes

Tags: primefaces

Hi people :) I have created a tree table using primefaces. In one of the table columns I have included 3 buttons. The problem is that the buttons work only for the first level and not for the second level. Can someone help me please. This is my treeTable code :

```xml
<h:form>
        <p:treeTable value="#{processBean.treeNode}" var="node" ajax="true"
            selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{node.id}">

            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{processBean.onSelect(node)}" />
            <f:facet name="header">Processes View</f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{node.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{node.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{node.description}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Created date">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{node.createdDate}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Status">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{node.status}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Actions" styleClass="centered-text">
                <p:commandButton title="Start" ajax="true"
                    icon="fa fa-play Fs16 white"
                    action="#{processBean.startProcess(node)}">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:spacer width="4%" />
                <p:commandButton title="Skip" ajax="true"
                    icon="fa fa-step-forward Fs16 White"
                    actionListener="#{processBean.skipProcess(node)}">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:spacer width="4%" />
                <p:commandButton title="Complete" ajax="true"
                    icon="fa fa-stop Fs16 white"
                    actionListener="#{processBean.completeProcess(node)}">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

        </p:treeTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error either in client or server side?

Comment: No error is shown. Just the method that must be called is not called. It is strange. It works for the highest level but for low levels not.

Comment: Check the browser tools (F12). Any Js error? Does any request get fired when you click?

Comment: I have checked it. No error there.

Comment: Tried PrimeFaces 6.2 or 6.3-SNAPSHOT instead of the unmentioned version you use. And what about your JSF version? And do you have a simple bean to accompany this xhtml?

Comment: No I have not tried to change it. I Will try now. I use primefaces 6.2 and jsf 2.2.13

Comment: There is no primefaces 6.3-SNAPSHOT in maven repository

Comment: Correct, you need to build that yourself from source, but 6.2 is already fairly recent and if you cannot find an issue related to something like this in github, there has most likely not been any change. Tried removing selection (and the related ajax call) and see if that makes a difference? And can you check if clicking on the commandButtons does fire an ajax call? And what the response is. Try adding `process="@this"` to the commandButtons

Comment: And tried using an `h:commandButton` with an `f:ajax` in it?

Comment: Did all but still nothing. No i didnt tried that. I tried using p:commandButton with a p:ajax but still nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1341535

Comment: I read it. Unfortunately none of these issues is my case :(

Comment: are you sure the method was not called? have you tried print something at the first line of method?

Comment: Yes, I use loggers

Comment: Hm, I had recently such behavior. I tried many hours, but my bean method wasn't called. But unfortunately I don't remember the position in my code. I had built a workaround....

Comment: I have solved it using javascript to perform http requests.